# Install Net 3.5 Framework on Windows Server 2012 without DVD

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-server-2012

I am trying to enable Net 3.5 Framework on Windows Server 2012. However, all the instructions I find on the Internet say I must have DVD of Windows Server 2012.

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/4146.installing-net-3-5-framework-on-microsoft-windows-server-2012.aspx

Since I do not have DVD I have been searching for where to download this feature.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To install the .net 3.5 on server 2012 without the disk (or disk image):

1. Ensure that the server is NOT looking at a WSUS server for updates (must be looking at Windows Update for this to work)
2. Ensure that any proxy/firewall will allow the connection from the server in question to the Windows update service
3. From a command line run:

   ```
   dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all
   ```

   The elimination of the source switch is done on purpose as this will force the server to look within its own SxS folder, not find the needed files, and then go to Windows Update for the files (hence step 1 where it is not pointing to a WSUS server).

Comment: did not work reporting _"The source files could not be downloaded."_

Comment: Hi! Could you please elaborate on on your first point? I cannot seem to find where to configure whether to use a WSUS server or not for updates.

Comment: EDIT: This seems to explain WSUS well: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tech-of-all-trades/a-simple-fix-for-microsoft-update-problems/

Comment: @MickyDuncan You need to disable WSUS

Comment: worked a treat  AFTER i did the following top answer for amending the group policy:

http://serverfault.com/questions/463604/unable-to-install-net-3-5-on-windows-server-2012

Comment: I disabled Windows Update quickly by temporarily renaming the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate` to `_WindowsUpdate`, then restarting the Windows Update service, then running the DISM command from above. After the install was successful I renamed the key back and restarted Windows Update again. This was especially helpful on Azure as finding the exact media that the install was done with is challenging.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure server to use Windows Update as a source for for optional components installation. And then install .NET 3.5 through the Add Roles and Features Wizard.

You can configure server by registry:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing]
"RepairContentServerSource"=DWORD(2)
```

or by Group Policy:

```
Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System
"Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair"
```

found here:

https://www.404techsupport.com/2012/11/server-2012-you-must-use-the-role-management-tool-to-install-or-configure-microsoft-net/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848079(v=vs.85).aspx?ppud=4&tduid=(ad1620201cdb131ba52a8e05b8ffef0c)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-mxEPD8HDp4sXn1EnYFo1cA)()

Answer (score 2):

I just manage to install it using a free trial evaluation of Windows 2012 R2.
https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise
I had to decompress the ISO, and Copy/paste the iso/sources/sxs folder to a temp folder to the server (less than 300Mo).
Regards.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your  method and its working. I used en-us link. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2?i=1

Answer (score 0):

WSUS is defined within a GPO.  I have an AD container that I have specifically defines the GPO to NOT use WSUS so that I can put a computer in that container and run GPUPDATE /FORCE.  That computer will then use Microsoft site for updates.  When complete I place the computer back in the container that has a GPO that specifies the WSUS server and again rung GPUPDATE /FORCE.

Using the Add Roles and Features does not provide a clear indication of the install process.  Using the command dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all allows the results to be more easily viewed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, doing a Windows Update (Important updates only) fixed this issue. (This server wasn't connected to WSUS.) So one of the currently available updates corrected it. I'm not sure which one. Also, MS has [released a fixit on this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/09/29/attempting-to-install-net-framework-3-5-on-windows-server-2012-r2-fails-with-error-code-0x800f0906-or-the-source-files-could-not-be-downloaded-even-when-supplying-source/).

> A fixit package just released for this issue. Please install the update in the following article to correct this issue:
>
> http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3005628